# Merge and make [crop] a synonym of [cropping]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I think making [crop](/questions/tagged/crop) a synonym of [cropping](/questions/tagged/cropping) is the more sensible way to have it go, in spite of the latter name being less frequently used, but it doesn't really matter which way it is.

Current usage is 731 [crop](/questions/tagged/crop) and 240 [cropping](/questions/tagged/cropping) questions.

Unless we're going to repurpose [crop](/questions/tagged/crop) to speak of corn crops, crop circles, turkey crops or bacon, one of them should go.

Comment: was going to suggest synonym but I don't have enough score in [crop] or [cropping]

Comment: Ditto—hence this post